# Capture Rails API Requests/Response with WireShark

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, http, request, wireshark

I'm working with the API using HTTMultiParty and I'm having trouble capturing the outgoing HTTP requests when I make POSTs. I don't see them at all in wireshark. I am capturing on the wireless adapter (I have no other internet connection) and filtering on

> http.host contains "docusign"

but I can't see anything come up. Even with just an HTTP filter, I see nothing new captured while I see a request and response. Why is wireshark unable to view the traffic from my rails app? Note: I can see the request made by my browser to the rails app.

Comment: Ah yes, they are made over https. I thought I'd at least see the traffic even though it was over SSL. I thought i remember seeing facebook traffic though. I didn't think of trying tcp.dest, but I'll try that now.

Answer (score 3):

Since it's https traffic, assuming you know the IP address of the server you're talking to, use the filter `ip.addr == x.x.x.x` and you should see TLS traffic leaving leaving your client.

I presume in the above comments that you mean "ip.dst" because there is no such thing as "tcp.dest" as far as I'm aware.

Slightly old but [here's a complete list of filters](http://packetlife.net/media/library/13/Wireshark_Display_Filters.pdf).